# In Dart, Is it not possible to inherit packages?

Tags: dart

```
import "dart:html";

class ParentClass {

}
```

---

```
import "ParentClass";

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  int main() {
    Element e = querySelector()
  }
}
```

Element & querySelector in ChildClass display as issues (Undefined Element & querySelector)

Is it not possible to import packages from ParentClass?

Comment: imports have to be at the top and not between class declarations. And you don't have to import the class if it's in one file. Please provide a complete example. You can use `export` to export existing libraries.

Comment: If you remove the `import "ParentClass";` I guess that it will do what you want - at least it will be a correct library where `Element` is imported. To keep terminology straight: You import *libraries*, you extend or inherit *classes*. Packages is a third concept, which is a way to distribute libraries. The main method of a Dart script should be a top-level function, not a class mehod.

Answer (score 1):

An import's scope is only the importing library.

If you import `dart:html` in the `ParentClass` library file and import the `ParentClass` library in another file, then the other file does not see the `dart:html` declarations.

There is two ways to handle that:

1. Preferably, just import `dart:html` in the other library too.
2. Export `dart:html` from the `ParentClass` library: add `export "dart:html";` next to `import "dart:html";`. That way the declarations of `dart:html` will be available to any library importing `ParentClass`.